# How can I recall a method within the same method?

Tags: java

I programming a blackjack and I want the method `play()` to be executed each time the player loses.  Such as:

```
public void play()
   {
      System.out.println("Your balance: $" + playerBalance + "\nHow much would you like to bet?");
      playerBet = keyboard.nextInt();
      System.out.println("Your bet: $" + playerBet);



      if(playerTotalValue > 21)
      {
         playerBalance -= playerBet;
         System.out.println("You are busted.\nYour balance: $" + playerBalance);
         System.out.println("Press enter to continue...");
         keyboard.next();
         play();
      }   

      else if(dealerTotalValue > 21)
      {
         playerBalance += playerBet;
         System.out.println("The house is busted.\nYour balance: $" + playerBalance);             
         System.out.println("Press enter to continue...");
         keyboard.next();
         play();
      }
```

This of course doesnt work as I want it to! Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: why does it not work? You just have a recursion without abort condition - which might be a bad idea.

Comment: yes, i figured.  We havent covered the topic of recursion in class.  Im in AP CS in high school.  So any advice is helpful.

Comment: it executes, but its an infinite loop.

Comment: Well repetition by recursion is a bad idea because - if not *tail recursion* or unoptimized - one will eventually run out of stack.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Calling a method from itself is called [*recursion*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursion_(computer_science)).

You don't want to do recursion for this, but rather a loop or cycle which keeps repeating its body until the player wants to quit.

Something like this:

```
public void play() {
    boolean playAgain = true;

    while (playAgain) {
        // Your game logic here.

        // When the game ends, ask the user if he/she wants to play again
        // and store the answer in the playAgain variable.
    }
}
```

Comment: Perhaps you should mention a `playAgain = ...` in the `while` loop. Some make the mistake forgetting to set the `playAgain` in the loop...

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you need to call your function from outside as endless loop like:

```
while (true){
    play();
}
```

Or any other condition that you can think of.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add more conditions. Like the situation when playerTotalValue is greater than dealerTotalValue and playerTotalValue<21 or vice versa.

Answer (score 0):

```
// Just add while condition in your method
public void play()
int count = 0;
int max-attempt = 5;
while(true) {
    try {
        // Some Code
        // break out of loop, or return, on success
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // handle exception
        if (++count >= max-attempt) throw e;
    }
}
}
```

Comment: I added max-attempt to avoid infinite loop! . I hope this will help you.